# Group a list of objects by multiple attributes

Tags: java, collections

I am looking for a nice way to group a list of objects by multiple class attributes. The [Google guava library](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) provides a feature to group by a single attribute. I haven't found a utility yet that offers what I am looking for.

See below. I have encapsulated the grouping attributes into its own class `Grouping`. However, this need not be necessary if a better solution exists.

A class that contains grouping attributes.

```
Class Grouping{

 private String key1;
 private String key2;
 private String key3;

 //getters, setters

}
```

Class representing a type that would need to be grouped.

```
Class Groupable{

 private Grouping grouping;

 private String x;
 private String y;
 private String z;

 // getters, setters

}
```

What I need is a Map that contains as key, a Groupable object with unique set of keys. And a list of Groupable objects as corresponding grouped items.

```
Map<Grouping, List<Groupable>> groupings;
```

Any and all suggestions welcome!

Comment: The method you linked to does exactly what you want: you pass a function that transforms a Groupable into a Grouping, and it does everything else. Of course, Grouping needs to implement hashCode() and equals() correctly. Where is the problem? Note that what it does is pretty easy to do with a simple Map.

Comment: Okay. I think I need to implement my own equals(). That is what I am missing, since the default implementation is looking for object equality, while I want to establish equality in object attributes. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget to implement a `hashCode()` that is consistent with your `equals()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question based on @JBNizet and @JohnBollinger's comments.

I use Eclipse IDE, so all I needed to do is to go to Source -> 'Generate hashCode() and equals()..' and invoke the same on my `Grouping` class to include all attributes in the overridden implementation. There on, guava library can be used in its regular way as below:

```
Function<Groupable, Grouping> groupFunction = new Function<Groupable, Grouping>(){

    @Override
    public Grouping apply(Groupable groupable) {

        return groupable.getGrouping();
    }

};

ImmutableListMultimap<Grouping, Groupable> groupings = Multimaps.index(lsGroupable, groupFunction);
```

`groupings` gives me what I need. `lsGroupable` is a list of `Groupable` objects.